# goland stop a test but stuck at "terminating Testxxxx. Waiting for process detech" on macos

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

When I run the test with goland test tool. I found that I cannot terminate the program.

If I use `command` + `w` to terminate it, it will come into a background task and stuck at `Waiting for process detech`

here is some screenshot of my goland:

**Run test:**

[image]

**Try to stop test with `command` + `w` or click stop button:**

[image]

**then, the stop button become to a skeleton icon:**

[image]

**Or like this:**

[image]

What I tried:

1. Create a new project by goland. -- failed
2. use `chmod -R 777 ./project_dir/`. -- failed
3. edit `run configuration` and enable `use sudo` -- ***success***
4. run test by terminal `go test -v -run ...` and used `command` + `c` -- ***success***

So this looks like a permissions issue. But I tried `chmod -R 777` and it didn't work.

Version:
GoLand 2022.3.2
MacOS: 13.2.1 (22D68)
Go: 1.20.1 with `brew instll` and `gvm`

Comment: Where's your project located on the file system? Is it an external or internal drive?

Comment: @s0xzwasd in my user folder`~/Documents/go/src/my_project_dir`